# Create JSON.NET structure with JTokenWriter

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Hey all I have the following json output that I would like to create:

```
{
    "scheduleName": "",
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "theRole": "",
    "linker": "",
    "Schedule": {
        "ID": "",
        "totalHrs": "",
        "Mon": "",
        "Tue": "",
        "Wed": "",
        "Thu": "",
        "Fri": "",
        "Sat": ""
    },
    "empInfo": {
        "ID": "",
        "Email": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "Active": "",
        "Img": "",
        "Badge": ""
    },
    "availability": {
        "ID": "",
        "Mon": "",
        "Tue": "",
        "Wed": "",
        "Thu": "",
        "Fri": "",
        "Sat": ""
    },
    "training": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
    }
}
```

Using the newtonsoft [Create JSON with JTokenWriter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonJTokenWriter.htm) I am wondering how to create the **"Schedule"**, **"empInfo"**, etc in my json output since there are no examples on the page of those types.

The only example it shows is structured like so:

```
{
  "name1": "value1",
  "name2": [
     1,
     2
  ]
}
```

The first few values are easy to create:

```
Dim jsonWriter As New JTokenWriter()

jsonWriter.WriteStartObject()
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("scheduleName")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("value1")
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("firstName")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("value2")
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("lastName")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("value3")
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("theRole")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("value4")
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("linker")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("value5")
'"?": {
'    "?": "?",
'    "?": "?",
'    etc....
'?
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject()
```

But that's where I have to stop since I do not know how to go about making the other structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write a nested object as the value of a property, write the property name, then do a nested [`WriteStartObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenWriter_WriteStartObject.htm), followed by the properties to be written, and finally a nested [`WriteEndObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteEndObject.htm).  E.g.:

```
Dim jsonWriter As New JTokenWriter()

jsonWriter.WriteStartObject() 'Start the root object
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("scheduleName")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("value1")

jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Schedule") 'Write the "Schedule" property name
jsonWriter.WriteStartObject() 'Start the nested "Schedule" object
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("ID")
jsonWriter.WriteValue("ID Value")
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject() 'End the Schedule object

jsonWriter.WriteEndObject() 'End the root object
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IMDNQU).

Comment: That did it. Thanks dbc!